# Fisher's Exact Test for 2x3 tables

Tags: references, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I'm writing my dissertation and I need to cite a source to support using the FET for 2x3 tables. Does anyone knows of a source that can be cited?

Answer (score 1):

Alan Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* is a great book to cite. Check section 3.5.1, though it's about 2 by 2 table, the spirit is similar.